# How to use the render result from one scene as a texture in another scene

Tags: rendering, texturing, compositing-nodes

Maybe there's a better way to go about this. What I want to do is render 2 scenes for every frame and use the result from the first render as a texture in the next.

Example:

Scene 2: A room animated with a computer on the desk.

Scene 1: The screen of the computer.

This probably isn't even possible in the method I'm describing, but I think you'll see what I'm getting at. How can this be done in Blender Internal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither Cycles not Blender-Internal support this, You just have to render out the files to an image or a movie, then load them in as an image texture afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure that something like this can't be done by texturing via a composite? The other day, I researched how to get Cycles lighting quality with the blender internal object outline effect. The answer (this worked well) was to create a duplicate of the scene and in the compositor render both of them and overlay. For every frame, both scenes were rendered and combined. Could that not be pipelined into a texture? 

Of course you may be completely right.

Comment: @JonathanTodd You could use compositing to combine both scenes in a way which would look okay, (you don't even need separate scenes, two renderlayers should be fine) but it would not technically be a texture.

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm open to it if it works. Post as an answer if that solution achieves the right effect. It would be more effective to be able to work on the scenes/render layers together rather than build the screen animation and apply it as a video texture. Having the character interact with the screen, any changes to the master scene animation would require re-rendering in the other scene separately. Maybe there's an easier way to do it? A trick that movie CGI editors use?

Comment: @Jonathan Todd - You could for example, use the compositor to overlay the output of one render onto another, using UV distortion to map it to a 3D surface, its a little more involved to have other objects in-front of it, but possible using Z-Masks.

Answer (score 1):

What I was [originally thinking of](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/how-to-use-the-render-result-from-one-scene-as-a-texture-in-another-scene#comment9818_6201) will not work as easily as I thought, however you could use an approach like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2613/599). Quoted from my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2612/599):

> You can achieve this with an *Image Sequence Texture node*:
>
> 1. Set up two render layers with each layer excluding the other:
>
>    [image]
> 2. Set up compositing nodes so the render layer that is being used to influence the materials renders out to a separate directory.    This
>      is possible with the *File Path* node:
>
>    [image]
> 3. Render only the influencing layer once to that directory by *Pinning* [image] that render layer.    The file will be named something like `Image0001.png`. Rename it to
>      `Image0000.png`
> 4. Set up the material you want to be influenced.   You can pull in the result of the other render layer by adding an *Image Texture
>      node*, setting the image to `Image0000.png`, setting the *Source* to
>      *Image Sequence*, and setting the *Offset* to `-1`
>
>    [image]
>
>    This is the result of the other render layer.
> 5. Render the animation. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>, or *Info > Render > Render Animation*
>
>    Here is a simple test with two spheres (one on each layer) and a
>      moving light source:
>
> [image]
>
> Keep in mind that with this technique, the two layers are one frame
>   apart. This could be fixed by rendering the influencing layer
>   completely beforehand, and adjusting the offset accordingly.

This should work in BI as well, using an image sequence texture (as opposed to an image sequence node).