# Infinite Tunnel Droste effect

Tags: animation, uv, compositing-nodes

I've been looking at videos that create what is called **[Droste Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect)** 
where an image contains smaller version of the same image and they spiral ifinitely into each other.

like Escher's *Print Gallery*

[image]

or

[image]

I've looked at the math behind this [here](http://www.josleys.com/article_show.php?id=82) but I don't know I would deform an image recursively to make it repeat itself endlessly,

There are a few videos creating this effect using a tool called Pixel Bender.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEauXI6fV2A

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WHdyG9mJaI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrUFx0f_GR0

How can an image be deformed like on the reference the videos to create an infinite tunnel in blender?

Comment: That is messing with my eyes in so many ways.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12373/599

Comment: You would like [mandelbulber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mandelbulber/)

Comment: Am I the only one who read "Pixel Blender" instead of "Pixel Bender"? :P

Comment: @gandalf3 no, I had to read it several times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is a messy node setup that  could be turned into one  python node "I'll try to do that " :
this is the node setup
[image: the number of the node-group is the recursion number]
this is the node-group 
[image: the content of the node group]
the object index in the node-group should be that of the "object of interest", also the is object is unwrapped before. 
[image: these should be the same]

finally here is a quick simple render :
[image: after compositing]

*the UV and ID outputs of the node group are only added to ease hooking up more nodes sequentially

Comment: Very nice! Now I need to figure out the distortion so the images blend within themselves as in the kid holding the frame... any ideas?

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: @PGmath 2.73 why?

Comment: @cegaton I meant Chebhou, there are five types of nodes to use (at the bottom, to the left of "use nodes").  I am used to three: material, compositing, texture; and I am wondering what the other two are.  I am using 2.73RC and I only have the three.

Comment: the first one is for the " animation nodes" Add-on , and the last one is for the "SVERCHOK" Add-on  which is parametric geometry creation node system. They are both very interesting and useful