# Infinite Droste Clock in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've been trying to re-create this effect I saw on a TV series:

[image: Initial Scene]

[image: Swivel]

Essentially, the phone box originates from the center of the clock, comes to the camera, swivels to the other side, and then the clock opens up. I know how to do the phone box animation and camera, but this clock really stumps me. I need to find out how to make it look this way and to have the swivel effect work. There seem to be droste plugins for some other software but none (that I could find) for blender. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Don't make people watch a video to understand what you want. Please edit your question and describe with words your objective, possibly add some references images.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21738/infinite-tunnel-droste-effect

Comment: Sorry for the video thing! I've edited the question.

Comment: Blender has a builtin addon to create spirals objects with bezier curves, those might help with this. Under *File > User Preferences Addons* Activate *Add Curve: Extra Objects*, then in the *3D View* `Shitf + A` > *Add > Curve > Spirals*

Comment: Good idea! I'm giving that a try, but I'm not sure about how the swivel effect will work.