# Combining an image sequence into a single image

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, workflow, compositing-nodes

I would like to combine an image sequence into a single image in a quick way.

I tried adding all the images into the compositor manually

[image]

But it will take a long time to add each node one by one.

[This](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5uiE1b8NDHM) is what type of result I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5017/599, possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3720/599

Comment: It would help if we knew what kind of information the images contain (renders of the same frame with different noise seeds? Or..?), and what you want the result to be

Comment: The images contain different frames of animation. And for the result I would like to average the frames together

Comment: A timelapse or a long exposure effect?

Comment: Long exposure effect

Comment: There is an exposure setting, and there is a motion blur setting. I'm not exactly sure how to get the result you want though.

Comment: Looks to me like you have the solution already (plus the video you linked described how the effects were achieved). What about your result are you unsatisfied with?

Comment: The problem is that I had to add one image node for every single image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really do recursive operations (loops) in the compositor, but in this case there is a sort of hack you can do (a bit like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5018/599) or [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12373/599)).

You *can* apply this to the animation as it's rendered, but I preferred to render everything to .exrs and composite afterwards.

1. Add an image sequence node (or renderlayer node) that gives the raw render output
2. Add an image sequence node pointing to the output directory where you'll render the combined sequence.
   To do this you may have to create a few dummy files to convince blender that there is an image sequence there. Copying at least the first few frames of the render output to this directory will do, but be sure to delete them once the node is added.
3. On the image sequence node, set *Frames* to the length of your render and the *Offset* to -1. Be sure that the start frame is set correctly as well.
   This will make the image sequence node read the previous frame.
4. Add a file output node or use a composite node and adjust the scene output settings. Set the output path to the directory the image sequence node is pointing to. You may want to render to .exr files so you can adjust the exposure later.

[image]

Then render the animation.

This will start by adding the first frame to nothing (as the 0th frame doesn't exist), then the second frame to the first, and the third to the combination of the first and second, and so on. The end result will be an animation like this:

[image]

The last frame is the result of all the frames added together:

[image]