# Is it possible to combine multiple frames into one still Cycles render to simulate long exposure?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a simple 20 frame animation. The objects in the scene are imported png files as planes.

I have the various planes scaling and moving over time - Is there a render option that allows me to capture this movement in one output image?

20 frames long exposure rendered as one flat tif file.

I have the render sequence set at 1-20, *Step* = 1

Motion blur and deformation are active for the moving objects.

All I can get is one frame rendered and I would like to avoid post-composition of multiple frames by hand.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41783/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-long-exposure-shot-in-blender
 
Hope this helps

Comment: [Combining an image sequence into a single image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32718/combining-an-image-seqence-into-a-single-image) or [stackikng cycles renders in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/stacking-cycles-renders-in-the-compositor)