# Is there a shader like this in blender CCTV

Tags: shaders

Looking around blender texturer and can't find anything that does this shader https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q2wFjitpZ0
Also looked in python camera stuff and found nothing that I can even recognize as a camera shader.
Can anyone point me to a shader or some blender python code that can get me at least on right road to make a shader like this?

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images and a detailed description of what you're after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Project scene to plane in real-time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115626/project-scene-to-plane-in-real-time) - TLDR is that in short, no, you cannot use a camera view as a texture on another object in real-time in blender. There are ways to "cheat" this, outlined in the linked answer, but it will still not be the "real thing".