# Is a Toon Ramp material with image textures possible?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, npr

Is it possible to set up a Toon Ramp Material that would use image textures instead of flat colors?

I usually do a Toon with Ramp checked, interpolation set to Constant, and input set to result to get a hard edge transition with full control over the "shadow" color.

In Maya you can plug image textures into the color slots on a ramp so you can cheat a cel shadow over an image texture by having a "normal" colored image transition to a "shadow" colored image.

Is there a node set-up for this? Is there another way to get this effect?

[image: toon_material]

Comment: I have always wanted to use shaders as a factor . . .

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2612/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create 3 materials:

- Toon with your setup with white and black colors
- A shadeless material with texture you wanna use on lit areas
- A shadeless material with texture for areas in shadow

Then you will combine them in 4th material using nodes like this:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much... exactly what I needed.